# Remotely running a script automatically after a specific time

Tags: linux, shell

I want to run a shell script on a remote cluster automatically.

So supposing I have a currently running script run1.sh in Directory Run1/ I want to automatically copy two very small files (created after run1.sh finishes) and then run the subsequent script run2.sh in Directory Run2 as soon as run1.sh finishes and the files are copied to Run2 as these are inputs for run2.sh.

Copying the files to Run2 is easy (I can just put the cp commands under my run command in the script run1.sh), what I don't understand is how to submit this script to run in Run2 after the copying

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two script files. One script file can do this.

Comment: How to run the command from the first script file into some other directory?